# Sample program that takes a long time to compile

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr

I am simulating some time out scenarios during compilation and would like to have some samples that take well over 30 seconds to compile on C++17. Can you suggest some examples that can do this? I am trying to use `constexpr` and I am not getting the timeouts I need. Sample I am using

```
constexpr auto delay()
{
    unsigned long long x = 0UL;
    for (unsigned long long i = 1; i < 1000000000UL; i++)
    {
        x++;
    }
    return x;
}
...
...
delay();
```

Comment: Does this strictly need to be C++ code that takes a long time to compile, or would other delays during compilation do the trick? E.g. sneaking a `sleep 30` somewhere in the build steps, or trying to compile the ["file"](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) `<(sleep 30)`?

Comment: It has to be in the compilation step. Just should take a long time to compile.

Comment: What does "in the compilation step" mean here? How is the code being compiled / what build system are you using?

Comment: In my current flow, I am starting a process which runs the cl.exe (VS compiler) with a bunch of options and I want to make compilation of a file/code in that process to timeout, so that I can test scenarios in my system.

Comment: You have to try harder! Anyone, including the compiler, knows that if you increment something N times, the result is N. It doesn't have to count on its fingers, it just knows.

Comment: In general, wasting time with trivial code is hard to pull off these days. The compilers have a lot of tools to deal with rank idiocy, so you have to be a smarter idiot.

Comment: Try a function that searches for an odd perfect number. It will show them.

Comment: To make the compilation take longer: 1) Set optimization on highest.  2) Use a lot of complicated code; your example is trival. 3) Use a lot of functions.  4) Use a lot of complicated macros (this will slow down the preprocessor). 5) Use variable and function names that only differ at character position 31.

Comment: Instead of just `delay();`, first try to replace with something like `constexpr auto a = delay();`. I tried on MSVC, and it gave up with error C2131, because loop is too long, and it suggests tweaking with `/constexpr:depth<NUMBER>`. And GCC seems to have a similar flag `-fconstexpr-loop-limit=`

Comment: Reminds me of the PostScript programmers who coded computing the image of a Mandelbrot set in PostScript. Printing that file would compute the image on the printer. Took a long time to print.

Comment: There are plenty of complicated usages of templated code that take a long time to compile. They also (often) consume a significant amount of memory during compilation. But the time taken (and memory usage) is highly variable between compilers, and affected by compilation (e.g. optimisation) settings.  Code with a loop (like your `delay()`) often does not reliably cause measurable delays, either at compile time or runtime - because compilers/optimisers are often too smart e.g. able to easily recognise and replace your loop with `return 500000000500000000ULL` which produces no observable delay

Comment: `constexpr int ackermann(int x, int y) { ...`

Comment: I wrote fibonacci as a constexpr function and called it a few times, and can produce the delay. I called the function until compiler complained about heap space.

Comment: @Peter - can you share a few examples of those templated code? Would like to look at them and try them as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Any more or less big project like OpenCV, or Qt, TensorFlow

Another possibility, generate the code automatically.

Comment: Code generation is a great idea, you can have arbitrary code sizes. Actually, pipe the C code through stdin on the fly.